# How to create highly available Solr cloud set up

Tags: solr, solrcloud, disaster-recovery

I am trying to build a Solr set up in two data centers.
BY configuring 5 Solr servers in Solr cloud and 5 ZKs.
Set is like this

First Data Center:
Solr Servers : 3
Zookepper : 3

Second Data Center:
Solr Servers : 2
Zookepper : 2

Both data center are part of same Solr cloud so set up look s like :
One Solr Cloud with 1 leader 4 follower.

The reason behind to do it in case one Data center goes down completely other one must be available always to support read an write request without interruption.

Now i read for ZK fault tolerance is 2F+1 so for 5 server set up minimum 3 servers must be online.
I could not find anything like this for Solr Cloud.
Could you please confirm how i can make this set up available always in case of disaster on one data center.

Answer (score 0):

It'll effectively be same as ZK. ZK is what controls the SOLRCloud. You would want to add a few more servers or create more nodes on same server machines to achieve required fault tolerance.

Comment: The problem is if i add more server in ZK cluster it still would be same reason say for 7 servers set up ZK 4 will be in one data centers and 3 will be in second with tolerance of 3 so if center with 4 servers goes down system will be come unavailable. Question is can i add one new server to surviving data center at that time and system can be operational ?

Comment: Oh! We are talking about losing entire data center here, then I don't think there is any solution with two data centers. You will certainly need a third site, else if you lose the data center where majority of your ZK nodes reside ZK cannot elect a leader for sure. One option is to run in a degraded mode, just serving read requests. (I have never done that, though). Here on, it becomes a question of determining a strategy with least risk.